# Flutter's SharePlus plugin refusing to share images claiming 'The source file doesn't exist'

Tags: flutter, image, plugins

Flutter's [SharePlus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus/changelog) plugin is refusing to share images, complaining

> PlatformException(Share failed, assets/slideshow/tom_riddle_harry_potter_tour.webp: The source file doesn't exist., null, null)

The source file does exist, it's correctly declared in pubspec.yaml, and displayed in the app elsewhere using `Image.asset(...` using the same path.

I've tried numerous things, I tried giving XFile the MimeType, that didn't work.
I thought 'maybe it just won't work on web', so I eliminated image sharing in the web app.

Well that got sharing in the web app working, using a fallback, but the problem persisted on Android. So I tried omitting the image's path; just using the file name (with extension). Nope.

I tried specifying the image path string in a different manner, shouldn't work, didn't.

I tried reading the code for XFile and so far as I can see instantiating an XFile using an image path is perfectly valid.

```
Share.shareXFiles([XFile("assets/slideshow/${presentLocation.pictureList[0]}", 
mimeType: "image/webp", 
name: presentLocation.name.split(".")[0])],
subject: presentLocation.name + presentLocation.emoji,
text: shareStr,
sharePositionOrigin: box!.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size).then((shareResult) async =>
                      {
                        if (shareResult.status ==
                            ShareResultStatus.success)
                          {
                            await MyApp.analytics.logShare(
                                contentType: "URL shared",
                                itemId: presentLocation.name,
                                method: "with image")
                          }
                      });
```

Am I misunderstanding XFile? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
 var asset = "assets/slideshow/${presentLocation.pictureList[0]}";

 ByteData imagebyte = await rootBundle.load(asset);
 final temp = await getTemporaryDirectory();
 final path = '${temp.path}/temp_image_name.png';
 File(path).writeAsBytesSync(imagebyte.buffer.asUint8List());

 await Share.shareXFiles(path, 
  mimeType: "image/webp", 
  // rest of code
```

To create temporary directory, `path-provider` package might be needed if you already don't have it.

https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

Comment: Yes that got it working on Android! But it would be great to have it working on web too. It doesn't like the temporary directory, complaining 
```Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getTemporaryDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)```

Comment: if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS){ // use the code in the answer } else { // Well that got sharing in the web app working, using a fallback, but the problem persisted on Android // do what you did above to get web working }

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's a different question really. Thankyou for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One may also attempt to directly utilize the *XFile.fromData* code, as it does not necessitate any extra reliance on *path-provider*.

```
String asset = "assets/slideshow/${presentLocation.pictureList[0]}";
ByteData imagebyte = await rootBundle.load(asset);
Share.shareXFiles([
    XFile.fromData(
        imagebyte.buffer.asUint8List(), 
        mimeType: 'image/webp', 
        name: presentLocation.pictureList[0])
]);
```