# Image not showing when sharing using the Flutter package share_plus

Tags: flutter, image, file-sharing, share-plus

I have been trying to create a share button in my Flutter application running on Windows that allows the sharing of images to social media platforms. I tried to use the [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) package in Flutter. Sharing texts works just fine. When I try to share an image, the image doesn't appear, and only the text is shared. Here is my code (based on the [example on the share_plus page](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus/example)):

```
final imageAsset = "assets/image2.png";
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final image = await rootBundle.load(imageAsset);
                final buffer = image.buffer;
                final bufferFile = XFile.fromData(
                      buffer.asUint8List(
                        image.offsetInBytes,
                        image.lengthInBytes,
                      ),
                      name: 'name',
                      mimeType: 'image/png',
                    );
                Share.shareXFiles(
                  [ bufferFile ],
                  subject: 'subject',
                );
              }
)
```

I also tried the answers of [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75051178/flutters-shareplus-plugin-refusing-to-share-images-claiming-the-source-file-do):

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                ByteData imagebyte = await rootBundle.load(imageAsset);
                final temp = await getTemporaryDirectory();
                final path = '${temp.path}/temp_image_name.png';
                File(path).writeAsBytesSync(imagebyte.buffer.asUint8List());

                await Share.shareXFiles([XFile(path, mimeType: "image/png")], 
                  subject: "Siem en Klaas",
                );
              }
)
```

which is slightly different (as it didn't work as the answer suggested), and

```
final imageAsset = "assets/image2.png";
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                ByteData imagebyte = await rootBundle.load(imageAsset);
                Share.shareXFiles([
                    XFile.fromData(
                        imagebyte.buffer.asUint8List(), 
                        mimeType: 'image/png', 
                        name: imageAsset.split("/").last.split(".")[0])
                  ],
                  subject: "subject",
                );
              }
)
```

I was able to show the image through the Image.asset widget all fine. Also, I had a look at whether the temporary file was created, and it was created in my user's Appdata folder. Furthermore, I am not receiving any error messages, which is extremely frustrating. As I am new to Flutter, I have the feeling that I have missed something outside of the main code, and must specify something in the pubspec or something. If anyone could help me, I would be most grateful! Also, I would be very happy to understand how to receive an error message in this case.

I tried to get create a functionality to share images using share_plus. Even though the sharing worked, and my app runs fine, the image doesn't appear!

Comment: I found the issue: share_plus doesn't work with the Windows emulator. I'm now using Android's Pixel 6 emulator and all works fine!